# How to use dll located in other folder in Visual Studio C++ project(Windows)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have debug and release dll from some library that weight a ton and updated from time to time. `Debug` and `Release` version .dll have the same name, without d.dll.

Is there a way I can add them to project without copying them into project folder?

I tried setting folder in `Debugging->Environment`, didnt worked. I added to Path system environment variable, it worked. But this way I have to change variable to whether Im building `Release` of `Debug`. I created my own env variable like `LIB_DEBUG`, but I do not know where to add it in Visual Studio for it to be able to grab dll.

Comment: Use the post-build event to xcopy /d the file to the build directory.  Do make sure this all this works five years from now when you forgot about it or are no longer around, keeping the original in the project directory and checked-in to source control is the wise choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to attack this, but typically you have a $(Platform)$(Configuration) macro
If you have a DLL "foo.dll" and there are two copies:

```
../Debug/foo.dll
../Release/foo.dll
```

Then you can set the properties for Library Directories to be
../$(Configuration)/foo.dll
And the linker will look in DEBUG for the DEBUG builds and Release for the Release Builds.
[image]

There is also an EXECUTEABLE path, but this only works within Visual Studio.  For runtime you will either need to distribute foo.dll with myfoo.exe in the same directory, or update the PATH enviornment variable to be either ../Debug/foo.dll or ../Release/foo.dll to avoid DLL Hell.

You could have a post build step that copies from

```
copy ../$(Configuration)/foo.dll $(TargetDir)
```

This will make sure the correct DLL is in the same location as the *.exe and this is the first place Windows looks for DLL's at runtime.